# Application Runs on AVD But Not On Device

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am new to Android Development.

I am currently stuck on a problem with my app.

The thing is I tested my app to fetch data from an online database and it works smoothly in the AVD. But when I uploaded the same to my cell phone, the app runs but is not able to connect to the internet. I have a gut feeling that this is related to Wi-Fi. Are there any kinds of additional permissions that I need my application to have? Or is there something that I need to add to my code?

My application has currently the INTERNET, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions.

Sorry if I sound too noobish, since I am a noob. Please help. If you need additional info please post in comments.

Comment: how do you check internet connection?

Comment: My phone is connected to the internet since I am able to use other applications like Browser and Whatsapp.

Comment: you see any error in logcat?

Comment: No. Is it necessary to write code to connect my app to wifi networks manually or will it automatically detect any network my phone is connected to?

Comment: You means have any code to check internet connection? and your device is connected to Wi-Fi or other network?

Comment: My device is connected to Wifi. But it seems my app is not able to use the connection.

Comment: please post your code